# First real program in C: Fibonacci sequence

Tags: c, fibonacci

I'm trying to write the first 10 terms of the Fibonacci sequence. I feel like I'm on the right line, but I can't seem to quite grasp the actual code (in C).

```
float fib = 0;
const float minn = 1;
const float maxn  = 20;
float n = minn;
while (n <= maxn);{
n = n + 1;
printf (" %4,2f", fib);
fib = (n - 1) + (n - 2);
}
```

Comment: This tutorial might be of use when learning about how to program for the fibonacci sequence: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/

Comment: `fib(n) != n-1 + n-2` => review your formula... (Otherwise you could easily determine that for n =10, fib is 17)

Comment: You add the *previous two elements* (starting with 0 & 1) to get the new number . So you need to store the previous two numbers (Your current logic doesn't have it). Think about how to do that.And you should remove that `;` from `while (n <= maxn);{` ASAP ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With the fibonacci sequence the value f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n = 2).  the first three values are defined as 0, 1, 1.

The fibonacci sequence is a sequence of integer values (math integers, not necessarily C language values).  consider using int or long for the fibonacci value.  float is worthless, it only adds unneeded overhead.

when calculating the fibonacci sequence you must store the previous 2 values to get the next value.

you want 10 fibonacci values.  you know the first three already so print those and then calculate the next seven values.

7 values implies a loop that iterates 7 times.  it has no bearing on the maximum value of the fibonacci value returned, just how many values you want to print.

do something like this:

```
printf("0, 1, 1");

int currentValue;
int valueN1 = 1;
int valueN2 = 1;

for (int counter = 1; counter <= 7; ++counter)
{
    currentValue = valueN1 + valueN2;
    printf(", %d", currentValue);

    valueN2 = valueN1;
    valueN1 = currentValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need run loop 10 times only,to find first 10 terms of the Fibonacci sequence.

in your code,while loop would not let you go further because of semicolon at the end of loop

```
//declare fib value as long int or unsigned int  
// because the value of any fib  term  is   not at all 
long int fib;
int n=1; 
while (n <= 10)
{
printf (" %d", fib);
fib = fib_term(n); 
n = n + 1;
}
```

[implement fib_term(int n); by seeing this snippet](http://www.writeaprogram.info/c/fibonacci-series-in-c/)

Comment: inter change   These two lines `printf (" %d", fib);`
`fib = fib_term(n);` because this prints first and then calls function to avoid this Just call first and then print.             `fib = fib_term(n); printf (" %d", fib);`

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would suggest changing your datatype from a float to an integer or other datatype.  floats are not exact numbers and if you had used while (n = maxn) instead of while (n <= maxn) you could have ended up with an infinite loap since the two floats would never have matched.

Second, you don't seem to really understand what the fibonacci sequence is. Take a look at the wikipedie article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number.

The fibinocci number is NOT (n - 1) + (n - 2) like you have.  It is the sum of the previous two numbers in the sequence.  You need to restructure your loop to hold the last two values and calculate the next one based on these values.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) 2 ways to implement the Fibonacci Algorithm in C:

The Iterative:

```
int fib(int n){   
    if (n == 0)
       return 0; 
    int a = 1   
    int b = 1;   
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {     
        int c = a + b;     
        a = b;     
        b = c;   
    }   
    return b; 
}
```

The Recursive:

```
unsigned int fibonacci_recursive(unsigned int n)
{
if (n == 0) 
{
    return 0;
} 
if (n == 1) {
       return 1;
}
return fibonacci_recursive(n - 1) + fibonacci_recursive(n - 2);
}

void main(){
    unsigned int i = fibonacci_recursive(10);
}
```

Comment: Should `fibonacci_recursive()` get called with `n < 0`, one would likely get Stack Overflow - what a nifty name for a website.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions

1. Consider integer types before FP types when doing integer problems.
2. Omit a `;` in your `while (n <= maxn);{`
3. Use a `.` in floating point formats `%4.2f` instead of `%4,2f`.
4. Fibonacci is the sum of the previous 2 terms, not simply `fib = (n - 1) + (n - 2)`.
5. Consider an `unsigned` solution:

C code:

```
void Fibonacci_Sequence(unsigned n) {
  const unsigned minn = 1;
  const unsigned maxn = 20;
  unsigned F[3];
  F[0] = 0;
  F[1] = 1;
  unsigned i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= maxn; i++) {
    if (i >= minn) printf(" %u,", F[0]);
    F[2] = F[1] + F[0];
    F[0] = F[1]; 
    F[1] = F[2]; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses n/2 iterations

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
                 int i,n,a=0,b=1,odd;
                 scanf("%d",&n);
                 odd=n%2;
                 for(i=1;i<=n/2;i++)
                 {
                                  printf("%d %d ",a,b);
                                  a=a+b;
                                  b=a+b;
                 }
                 if(odd)
                 printf("%d",a);
}
```